# add julia to path for easy start program

Tags: unix, julia

In julia, I always start the program by typing

```
exec /Applications/Julia-0.3.2.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia
```

in command line. 
How could I add "/Applications/Julia-0.3.2.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia" into PATH or set a variable so I don't need type all the directory everytime using julia?
BTW, i'm using mac os.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution, add following command to profile and refresh the terminal:

```
alias julia='exec /Applications/Julia-0.3.2.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia'
```